# updating html elements with ajax json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I use this script to update table cells based on ajax request with json response. The thing it does not update the specified table cells. Is my json string not formatted correctly?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('select.swcomp').change(function () {
        var res_id = $(this).val();
        var index = $(this).data('index');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'http://skiweather.eu/v3/ajax/compare_snow.php',
            data: '{ "res_id":"' + res_id + '", "index":"' + index + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#destin_' + index).html(response.resort);               
                $('#snowval_' + index).html(response.snow_valley);
                $('#snowmnt_' + index).html(response.snow_mountain);            
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

html

```
 <select name="resort_1" class="swcomp" data-index="1">
                    <option value="NoResort">resorts</option>
                    <option value="6">Adelboden</option>
                    <option value="237">Davos</option>
</select>

<table>
    <tr><td id="destin_1">res</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="snowval_1">val</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="snowmnt_1">mnt</td></tr>
</table>
```

json

```
var response =[{"snow_valley":"40","snow_mountain":"40","resort":"Adelboden"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

response is not an object, it is an array so `response.resort` is undefined it should be `response[0].resort`

```
$('#destin_' + index).html(response[0].resort);               
$('#snowval_' + index).html(response[0].snow_valley);
$('#snowmnt_' + index).html(response[0].snow_mountain);
```

Comment: Made the changes but it still does not update the table http://skiweather.eu/benchmark.php

Comment: your ajax response is not proper... it is `var response =[]` instead of `[{"snow_valley":"40","snow_mountain":"40","resort":"Adelboden"}]`

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The json string is not correctly formatted?

Comment: what do i need to change Arun?

Comment: @mark the response should be like `[{"snow_valley":"40","snow_mountain":"40","resort":"Adelboden"}]` no `var response = xxx`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40454/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-mark)

Answer (score 0):

yes your received json formatted correctly . if your want check your json farmatted correctly follow this site http://jsonlint.com/ it will check your json validation. for accessing json data http://jsontree.com/ simply paste your json and parse it will provide how easily acess data